# How to cherry pick from 1 branch to another

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have 2 branches, `master` and `dev`.

I am on `dev` branch and I want to cherry-pick 1 commit from `master` to `dev`. So I did

```
$ git cherry-pick be530cec7748e037c665bd5a585e6d9ce11bc8ad
Finished one cherry-pick.
```

But when I do `git status` and `gitx`, I don't see my commit `be530cec7748e037c665bd5a585e6d9ce11bc8ad` in git history.

How can I see my commit in the `dev` branch?

Answer (score 429, accepted):

When you cherry-pick, it creates a new commit with a new SHA. If you do:

```
git cherry-pick -x <sha>
```

then at least you'll get the commit message from the original commit appended to your new commit, along with the original SHA, which is very useful for tracking cherry-picks.

Comment: the '-x' is to append a line to the message that indicates where the commit was cherry-picked from. Useful only for public branches, not so much when cherry-picking from a local (private) branch to a public branch.

Comment: the "-x" is optional though.

Answer (score 14):

If you're an **IntelliJ** user, it's pretty simple.
Here, I am **cherry-picking** a commit from `master` branch to `give-me-commit-branch`. Note a few points in the below pic:

- **destination**: The current checkout branch is `give-me-a-commit-branch`. Denoted by *tag* icon.
- **source**: The selected `master` branch whose commit logs are displayed on the right side is the source of the commit.
- **searching ability**: Using the search (lens icon) option, we can find the revision number.
- **multiple-selections**: At a time, we can select multiple commits and cherry-pick them at one go!

This is easy-to-use and transparent.

[image]