# How to squash a merge commit with a normal commit?

Tags: git, github, merge, commit, squash

```
commit b0e5db36ed68d4562275adeb08001b1316a4da52
Merge: ea38baa 8220bb1

commit ea38baa3f46a48722987b8dd3892d2b8d81c4d1a
```

In this case how do I squash these two commits

I am using

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

but this doesn't work as it removes the Merge commit and that is not available for squashing

Comment: 'Please Help.' Everytime I read this I got something going on in my throat... I flag this question as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136558/git-how-to-squash-commits-which-have-merge-commit-in-between

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to squash commits which have merge-commit in between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136558/git-how-to-squash-commits-which-have-merge-commit-in-between)

Comment: Clearly *not* a duplicate of "How to squash commits which have merge-commit in between", because this question is about how to squash *with the merge commit itself*.  (To be clear: the same *answer* might work, but it's not the same question and someone searching for this isn't likely to find the other question and think it's the solution.)

Comment: I'd say "dont't", but maybe if you tell why do you need there is something else you should do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So two factors to consider here:

First, in a few ways `rebase` doesn't always play nice with merge commits.  I'll come back to that a couple times.

Second, it's not entirely clear what result you're expecting.  If right now you have something like

```
x -- x -- M -- C <--(master)
 \       /
  A --- B
```

are you trying to end up with

```
x -- x -- ABC <--(master)
```

or

```
x -- x -- MC <--(master)
 \       /
  A --- B
```

If you want the version with `ABC`, it's pretty simple.  While `M` doesn't appear in the TODO list of a rebase, all of the commits that were brought into the mainline *by* `M` (i.e. `A` and `B` in this example) are.  So just mark `B` and `C` for "squash".  The only thing to remember is that this is a history rewrite, so if you have already pushed any refs that can reach `A`, `B`, `M`, or `C` then some clean-up may be needed (see the `rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase").

If you want the version with `MC`, then there are a lot of problems.  Not that you can't get it, but I don't think you can get it by doing a `rebase`; and also, `MC` would be an "evil merge", which could cause problems with future `rebase` attempts as well (among other things).

By default `rebase` tries to produce a linear history and won't produce merge commits.  You can get it to produce merge commits with the `--preserve-merges` option, but this doesn't interact well with `-i` (and if you were to try to modify a merge by doing it, I anticipate several possible problems).

If you're not worried about the problems of hiding changes in a merge commit, and really want to produce a commit like `MC`, then the way to do it is:

First, move the `master` ref back to `M` while keeping the changes from `C` in the index.

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Then re-apply the changes directly to the merge commit

```
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer says, `git rebase -i` (aka `--interactive`) supports an additional option `-p` (aka `--preserve-merges`). However, unlike the accepted answer, I wanted to point out that this actually seems to work fine to achieve exactly the desired result, so that if you do `git rebase -i -p HEAD~2` the merge commit appears in the interactive rebase file:

```
pick abcdeff Merge branch 'feature' into develop
pick abcdefc Extra changes
```

Now you can edit this rebase file to mark the second commit for squashing and finish the rebase. It all seems to work fine.

However, I do not understand the intricacies of why the git documentation [warns against using using `-i -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_bugs) (and in some, but not all, versions of the documentation says that `-p` is deprecated) so your mileage may vary. It seems that the main problems come when trying to re-order the commits displayed when using this... so don't do that!

The recommended alternative to the deprecated `-p` option seems to be `git rebase -i -r`; but that produces a very long and complex interactive rebase file which looks nothing at all like what I am expecting (i.e. the simple rebase file shown as text above).

If anybody can add an answer explaining in any detail whether and why `git rebase -i -p` is (or isn't) okay in this case, that would be very helpful.